# Led turns on immediately after connecting it to the Power pin on Expansion Header

Tags: gpio, led

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 model B, and whenever I connect a resistor and LED to the 5 Volt pin and the ground pin it immediately turns on without any programming to enable it. I just want to know wether this is normal behaviour, since I thought that you're supposed to turn the pins on programatically.

Comment: you are connecting an LED and resistor between a power pin and ground?  .... you would have to include a switch if you want to turn off the LED .... or you could connect the LED to one of the GPIO pins instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5V pin is always "on" in the sense that you mean it.  It is not one of the GPIO pins, even though it is on the same header and looks the same.  The GPIO pins are the ones that you can control programmatically.

Comment: Useful dynamic site for GPIO info : https://pinout.xyz